# Sql query to get newest comment added joined 3 tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a sql query, that gets me the registration_timestamp of the newest comment.
By supplying a category id.

I have three tables. ( seen below with the fields that should be needed)

```
Ctm_Comments{
  Id,
  Page_ID,
  Registration_Timestamp
}

Ctm_Forum_Categories{
  Id
}
Ctm_Forum_Posts{
  Id,
  FK_Category_ID
}
```

I have tried the following, and it returns zero results.

```
var query = from p in Ctm_Forum_Posts
                    join c in Ctm_Forum_Categories on p.FK_Categori_ID equals c.Id
                    join ctm in Ctm_Comments on p.Id equals ctm.Page_ID
                    where c.Id == 1
                    select ctm.Reqistration_timestamp;
```

SQL Queries like these are not my strong suit, so i hope someone here can help out.

---

Ended up with this, based on the response from accepted answer.

```
var query = (from comments in Ctm_Comments
             join posts in Ctm_Forum_Posts on comments.Page_ID equals posts.Id
             join category in Ctm_Forum_Categories on posts.FK_Categori_ID equals category.Id
             where category.Id == 1
             orderby comments.Reqistration_timestamp descending
             select comments.Reqistration_timestamp).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: There isn't really any point in adding the orderby in that way - it wasn't my suggestion. I said to either take the Max of the query result or to order by descending on the timestamp and take the first whole comment object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SQL (MS SQL) Query needed is**

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Registration_Timestamp]
FROM [dbo].[Ctm_Comments] AS C
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ctm_Forum_Posts] AS P ON C.Page_ID = P.Id
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ctm_Forum_Categories] AS CAT ON CAT.Id = P.Category_ID
WHERE CAT.Id = 1
ORDER BY C.Registration_Timestamp DESC
```

and this is if we accept that PageID (of Comments Table) is the Post Id. **Otherwise, you are missing the PostId Column in the table of Comments which should be the join point**

***Run the Script below in SQL Server Studio for verification***

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ctm_Comments] ( [Id] [int] NULL,[Page_ID] [int] NULL,[Registration_Timestamp] [datetime] NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ctm_Forum_Categories] ( [Id] [int] NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ctm_Forum_Posts] ( [Id] [int] NULL,[Category_ID] [int] NULL) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Ctm_Comments] VALUES (1, 1, '2020-10-23 13:12:55')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Ctm_Comments] VALUES (2, 1, '2020-10-26 12:12:55')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Ctm_Comments] VALUES (3, 1, '2020-10-26 12:25:55')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Ctm_Comments] VALUES (4, 1, '2020-10-26 13:12:55')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Ctm_Forum_Categories] VALUES (1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Ctm_Forum_Posts] VALUES (1, 1)

SELECT TOP 1 [Registration_Timestamp]
FROM [dbo].[Ctm_Comments] AS C
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ctm_Forum_Posts] AS P ON C.Page_ID = P.Id
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ctm_Forum_Categories] AS CAT ON CAT.Id  = P.Category_ID
WHERE CAT.Id = 1
ORDER BY C.Registration_Timestamp DESC


DROP TABLE [dbo].[Ctm_Comments]
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Ctm_Forum_Categories]
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Ctm_Forum_Posts]
```

the Result is `2020-10-26 13:12:55.000`

Comment: I can get the result i need, but not really in the format i need. I need to use this in a c# class to make a call to the db. so i am currently unsure how to do that with this...

Comment: I figured it out ^^ Thx for the help!

Comment: Happy for that :)

Answer (score 1):

When you fix the "my query returns 0 results" part, I'd suggest something like this:

```
var mostRecentCommentTimestamp = query.Max();
```

But as you've only selected timestamps, this can only tell you the max timestamp, nothing else about the comment

If you want the whole most recent comment swap the select for an order by descending on the timestamp and take the first*, or install morelinq and use their MaxBy

*Edit, like this:

```
var query =     from p in Ctm_Forum_Posts
                join c in Ctm_Forum_Categories on p.FK_Categori_ID equals c.Id
                join ctm in Ctm_Comments on p.Id equals ctm.Page_ID
                where c.Id == 1
                orderby ctm.Reqistration_timestamp descending
                select ctm;
var firstComment = query.First();
```

All this said, at the moment you say your query produces no results; you need to fix that (the joins are wrong, or there is no category 1, or the db is missing data) before you can get a max/orderby of anything

Comment: I'm not sure anyone can help if your query "returns nothing" - it implies you've either got no data to query or that you've made an error in a join. I note that your LINQ says "Categori" but your SQL schema claim says "Category"; I would expect this to produce an error. All in, something isn't right, but you do really need to add some more info to your question, such as example data from category 1, for all tables so we can see what "isn't right" if you aren't doing that part